# How to isolate from installed libraries in hg repo for testing?

Tags: perl

How can I use local hg repo libraries for testing isolating from already installed libs?

Installed production perl package and local hg repo has the same structure

```
    +-- lib
        |-- modA.pm
        |-- modB.pm
    +-- bin
        |-- example.pl
    +-- t
        |-- modA.t
        |-- modB.t
```

libraries installed at and the path is added to @PERL5

```
/nfs_share/perl/
env|grep -i perl
PERL5:/usr/local/perl:/nfs_share/perl
```

local hg repo at:

```
/data/user/hg/perl
```

modB.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use modA;
sub modB_compare{
    my (x,y) = @_;
    # .....
    return x-y;
}
```

bin/example.pl

```
use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib "${Bin}/lib/";
use modA, modB;
# if this call is from local lib
my $result = modB_compare(x,y);
# if sub being called from production or local hg?
my $result2 = modA_method();
# from local hg repo or from production lib?!
```

If I were to modify and test in local hg repo, there is no gurantee that the lib I called is from local repo, not from the production libs.

What is the potential solutions for isolation the libraries for testing in a local hg repo?

Comment: I think you might need to expand this question a bit to get an answer. It's somewhat unclear what you're actually asking. You will get warned if you redefine a subroutine with an import operation. But from [`perlmod`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) you can fiddle with typeglobs `\*somesub{PACKAGE}` - that won't necessary help if you've imported it into your local symbol table though.

Comment: you are right, the question is not clear, I will take some time to rewordiing it

Comment: I totally agree with the hold. thanks

Comment: One more clarification if I may - are you using a generic `Exporter` so the `use` also implicitly imports a bunch of subs into the current namespace? (And are you using `warnings` because that tells you when a sub is redefined)

Comment: I never use Exporter, I am not familiar with it, I will take a look later on. I am using warning in perl script, but not on these 3 modx.pm, I did not get redefined from perl script.

Comment: `Exporter` is a thing your modules would be using to export their subs. So they get inserted into the current namespace. If that's the case, it's going to be hard, because .... the sub _is_ a local 'thing'.

Comment: I see. most of our perl is not OO, use lib is enough to use the subs

Comment: Exporter is mostly used with non-OO Perl code. When you `use` a module, Perl will actually do `BEGIN { require modX; modX->import; }`. That `import` method comes from Exporter. That will (usually) copy subs into the namespace that the `use` was called from. That's usually `main` when you are in a `.pl` file. So what @Sobrique is talking about is: *how do you get `modB_compare` into your `example.pl` file? Maybe [edit] and show some of the code of `modA.pm` and `modB.pm`. That would help to understand some context.

Comment: Just make sure `/data/user/hg/perl` is first in `@INC`. An easy way to do this is by changing the PERL5LIB environment variable.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, It is a viable, practical option for me. If you think `set_INC_PERL5LIB.sh ; hg/bin/example.t` will not affect production, I encourage you to elaborate it into an  answer, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: for tests, just use [`prove -l`](https://metacpan.org/pod/prove).

> If I were to modify and test in local hg repo, there is no gurantee that the lib I called is from local repo, not from the production libs.

**Actually, there is,** for the problem you've defined.

If you know that `./lib/modA.pm` exists and `./lib/` in `@INC`, then `./lib/modA.pm` will be loaded and any system perl version won't be*.

Your `use lib` statement does this for you as documented in [perlvar @INC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25INC) and [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html).

However, for tests, it's normal practice **not** to `use lib`, but **instead** use the [`-I` flag in perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) (`perl -Ilib t/modA.t`) or, better, [prove](https://metacpan.org/pod/prove), which also has a `-l` flag, so you can just do `prove -l` and it runs all the tests in `t/` using the modules in `./lib`.

NB: You might also want to look into [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker) or [Module::Build::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Build::Tiny) which help with distribution tasks, and you might want to consider [Dist::Zilla](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Milla) or (for a quicker start) [Dist::Milla](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Milla)

If you just want to verify what's going on You can check which files have been loaded in `use` or `require` statements by looking at [%INC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%INC).

If you *absolutely have to* control what modules are accessible, for instance because you want to test different behaviour depending on whether third-party modules are installed (rather than your own code), I suggest looking into [perlbrew](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::perlbrew). This will help you compile your own perl (of almost any vaguely recent version) which does not use the libraries from system perl, but instead has its own libraries, using `local::lib`; you can then switch between multiple installed perls. The only exceptions are libraries that are packaged with perl itself; you can get a list of these from [Module::Corelist](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::CoreList).

Finally, you might want to check out [Carton](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carton). I don't think it's quite what you're asking for but it's such a similar problem domain that I think it's worth a mention.

---

* OK, strictly, `lib` has to appear in `@INC` *before* the system perl lib directories, because what happens is that perl goes through @INC *in order* and finds files corresponding to the package name you have asked it to load; all of the methods you've used and that I'm talking about in this answer will make sure that your `lib` directory appears earlier in `@INC` then your system perl libs.

Answer (score 2):

This is potentially a bit of a can of worms - because any time you try to maintain concurrent 'installed' versions, you can very easily trip over incorrect dependencies. It's doable, but you have to be particularly careful when making the switch that you're not accidentally using a 'wrong' version.

As a result - for this sort of scenario, I'm using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). At risk of simplifying a bit, it's a way of packaging up your application instance with it's dependencies into a sort of mini virtual machine.

You create an image from a docker file, which is quite similar to a make file, except it 'builds' into an image, that you can then run - which includes your application and all it's dependencies.

I am also using Docker containers for my production instances, which I appreciate may not be a viable answer in your environment. But the point of me doing so is that I can develop to my heart's content, then when I'm ready for a release build a new 'reference' image to hand off to test.

If that ref image passes, then *exactly the same image* gets deployed into prod. Because it's self contained, and packaged with all it's dependencies, I get a high degree of confidence that I won't trip over on version skew of installed libs, nor will I get tripped up on a future update breaking anything - because everything my 'version' needs to run is part of the image.

But as a result, you have a very clean environment, and almost never have to worry about the things you're worrying about.

You can even *fairly* safely run your dev/ref/prod on the same physical tin, and just bind/map different resources (volumes/ports, etc.) to differentiate.